# no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.1.1.91", user "user" database "testing", SSL off

Tags: postgresql, ssl

I've come across different versions of this same issue on stackoverflow and on this forum. I've tried the recommendations posted on these forums but I am still unable to connect to a database. I've run out of leads to try and I'm hoping someone can explain to me what is happening and why I am unable to connect. The context of my question follows:

I pg_dumped a database on a server host named test-crawl-1 and have pg_restored the database onto a new server host named test-qa-db where it resides with 4 other databases. I've changed the database. yml file to look like this:

```
testing:
  db_host: test-qa-db
  db_port: 5432
  db_name: testing
  db_user: user
  db_pass: password
```

Next, because of the error I'm receiving I tried the following, I sshed into a VM named test-utility-1 and modified the pg_hba.conf file there to reflect the following:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

#Trying to fix the SSL error
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Then I tried this:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

#Trying to fix the SSL off error attempt 2
 local  all      all   (test-utility-1 address)10.1.1.1/32      md5
```

And then I tried to implement in the postgresql.conf file:

```
postgresql.conf

listen_addresses = "*"
```

I pretty much tried that line with the above variations but I have still yet been able to make it work. Is there anything that I'm missing. I'm not sure what else is there to try. Help would be appreciated thank you.

------------EDIT----------

I forgot to mention that I also hard coded the database, user, and Ip address into the corresponding fields but the SSl but the error still persists.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I was configuring the wrong pg_hba.conf file. I needed to configure the file in test-qa-db because that was where the database resided.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following line,

host 10.1.1.91 all all 10.1.1.91/32 md5

in your pg_hba.conf and reload your configuration ?

Perhaps you should see,

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Client_Authentication

Regards